# django AbstractUser model 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, django-users

I can not register a custom User model in the admin.py. No admin.py , all works fine

Why do the customUser? I not know what this is problems. I did everything according to the documentation

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

AbstractUser._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
AbstractUser._meta.get_field('email').blank = False


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_agency = models.BooleanField(_('agency status'), default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def get_is_agency(self):
        return self.is_agency
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from settings import AUTH_USER_MODEL as CustomUser

admin.site.register(CustomUser, UserAdmin)
```

Traceback

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f169c48a730>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 23, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/reklama/user/admin.py", line 32, in <module>
    admin.site.register(CustomUser, UserAdmin)
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 87, in register
    if model._meta.abstract:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is importing the string name of your user model, not the actual class.

```
from settings import AUTH_USER_MODEL as CustomUser
```

You should import the class from your `models.py` file.

```
from <app_name>.models import User as CustomUser
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible reasons for this:

1)
If you use this
`admin.site.register(classname)` (with single/double quotes) it generates an error

Instead use this:

```
admin.site.register(**classname**)  # (without single/double quotes)
```

2)
If you forget to import **class** in `admin.py`, the same error is generated.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the application independent you should use:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

CustomUser = get_user_model()
```

You can check what it does  [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e197dcca366cf0b7203123e4ba7f8962e1d69e72/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L155)